# how to create Java getters and setters when object key is number

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I cannot create Java Getters and Setters, because I got number(digit) for my Object Key.
I will show you my API response. How can I achieve this without changing the API.

```
    {"api_status": true,
    "message": "",
     "data": {
        "0": {
          "id": "aaa",
          "name": "aaa",
          "address": "aaa",
          "category": "aaa",
          "open_24_hours": "aaa",
          "business_open": "",
          "business_close": "",
          "type": "0",
          "title": null,
          "latitude": "6.8729428",
          "longitude": "79.8689013",
          "city": "",
          "distance": "2.95555089735992"
           },
       "1": {
          "id": "bbb",
           "name": "bbb",
           "address": "bbb",
           "category": "bbb",
           "open_24_hours": "bbb",
           "business_open": "",
           "business_close": "",
           "type": "0",
           "title": null,
           "latitude": "6.8767581",
           "longitude": "79.8674747",
           "city": "",
           "distance": "2.915385898910569"
         },
   }
  }
```

Comment: This is not a correct json format

Comment: It is correct but it's weird.

Comment: `last` comma is wrong, probably just a copy-and-paste of a sample range

Comment: Oh yeah @ScaryWombat , Hadn't noticed that, I thought he was referring to the keys "0" and "1". It's not wrong, it's just non-conventional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the below class and pass it to GSON library with your json data and the Class As a model . you will get your model, each data item is mapped with hashtable where key is your number which i represent as string By iterating over hash map you will get keySet which is your all keys in the data key of json. and for each key you can get itemData.

```
class JsonStructure{
public boolean api_status;
public String message
HashMap<String,ItemsData> data;
}


class ItemsData{
public String id;
public String name;
public String address;
public String category;
public String open_24_hours;
public String business_open;
public String business_close;
public String type;
public String title;
public String latitude;
public String longitude;
public String city;
public String distance;

}
```

**For retrofit Build**

```
BuildRetrofit(){
 mOkHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                 .addInterceptor(interceptor)
                .connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .build();
        mConverterFactory = GsonConverterFactory.create();
    String baseUrl = "http://dev.appslanka.com/";
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                .client(mOkHttpClient)
                .addConverterFactory(mConverterFactory)
                .build();
        mApi = retrofit.create(ApiInterface.class);
        }
```

**In ApiInterface   define yoyr request method**

```
interface ApiInterface{

  @GET("_test/placeInDistance/")
Call<JsonStructure> getResponseForApiCall();
}
```

**Now call this method as retrofit call structure:**

```
Call<JsonStructure> call = mApi.getResponseForApiCall();
        Response<JsonStructure> response = call.execute();
```

**Parse this response like below:**

```
HashMap<String, ItemsData> map = response .data;
            Set<String> s = map.keySet();
            Iterator<String> i = s.iterator();
            while (i.hasNext()){
                String key = i.next();
                ItemsData data = map.get(key);
                String id = data.id;
                String name = data.name;
                String address = data.address;
                String category = data.category;
                String open24Hr = data.open_24_hours;
                String businessOpen = data.business_open;
                String close = data.business_close;
                String latitue = data.latitude;
                ..... etc

            }
```

Comment: Thanks Ashif Ahamad,  Can you explain how to add this solution for retrofit API call?

Comment: @ AshifAhamad, Thank for reply.. I got null point. Please check my code

   `public void onResponse(Call<ResponseData> call, 
                Response<ResponseData> responseHome) {

                        for(int x=0; x< responseHome.body().data.size(); x++) {
                            System.out.println("getData().size()
                      "+responseHome.body().data.get("name"));

                        }
    }`

Comment: @UdithaAmarasinghe where you are getting null pointer could you please show me the logs..

Comment: @UdithaAmarasinghe you are fetching data incorrectly  responseHome.body().data.get("name") this is wrong way of fetching you have HashMap<String , ItemsData >  items= responseHome.body().data;

Now iterate this hashMap object items with iterator to get the actual value

Comment: I added your code but still I got null point, Please help me.

here is activity 

 `HashMap<String, ItemsData> items = responseHome.body().data;
 for (int x = 0; x < items.size(); x++) {      
  System.out.println("id " + items.get("id"));}`

Here is my interface class

`@GET("method?")
Call<JsonStructure> place(@Query("distance") String distance);`

and here is my API call
`retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
.client(ApiRequestClient.getOkHttpClient(mContext))
.baseUrl("url")
.addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
 .build();`

Comment: @Uditha Please give your complete request url i will write code aacordingly

Comment: @UdithaAmarasinghe  Please give your complete request url i will write code aacordingly

Comment: url = http://dev.appslanka.com/_test// , method name = placeInDistance/ @AshifAhamad

Comment: @UdithaAmarasinghe hi uditha i updated the answer please check it its working properly please follow the above described steps. And please please vote . If face any problem let me know thanks.

Comment: this works perfectly, thank you very much.. appreciate your help and support. @AshifAhamad

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. Use `SerializedName` annotation like this:

```
@SerializedName("0")
private MyClass myObject;
```

Where `MyClass` is gonna represent a `POJO` for the data you're getting back.

> I just want to note that a better solution would be to change the **API** (cause this response is weird), to return a list rather than an object with digits for keys, but I can see that you wrote in the question that you **cannot** change it.

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to parse this JSON. Use custom solution. 
For example my solution.
Create class Response with following code :

```
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Response {

public boolean apiStatus;

public String message;

public List<Data> datas;

public Response(JSONObject jsonObject) {
    apiStatus = jsonObject.optBoolean("api_status");
    message = jsonObject.optString("message");
    datas = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        JSONObject datasJSON = jsonObject.getJSONObject("data");

        int index = 0;
        while (datasJSON.has(String.valueOf(index))) {
            JSONObject dataJSON = datasJSON.getJSONObject(String.valueOf(index));
            datas.add(new Data(dataJSON));
            index++;
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override public String toString() {
    return "Response{" +
            "apiStatus=" + apiStatus +
            ", message='" + message + '\'' +
            ", datas=" + datas +
            '}';
}
}
```

Create class Data with following code :

```
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class Data {
public String id;

public String name;

public String address;

public String category;

public String open24Hours;

public String businessOpen;

public String businessClose;

public String type;

public String title;

public String latitude;

public String longitude;

public String city;

public String distance;

public Data(JSONObject jsonObject) {
    id = jsonObject.optString("id");
    name = jsonObject.optString("name");
    address = jsonObject.optString("address");
    category = jsonObject.optString("category");
    open24Hours = jsonObject.optString("open_24_hours");
    businessOpen = jsonObject.optString("business_open");
    businessClose = jsonObject.optString("business_close");
    type = jsonObject.optString("type");
    title = jsonObject.optString("title");
    latitude = jsonObject.optString("latitude");
    longitude = jsonObject.optString("longitude");
    city = jsonObject.optString("city");
    distance = jsonObject.optString("distance");
}

@Override public String toString() {
    return "Data{" +
            "id='" + id + '\'' +
            ", name='" + name + '\'' +
            ", address='" + address + '\'' +
            ", category='" + category + '\'' +
            ", open24Hours='" + open24Hours + '\'' +
            ", businessOpen='" + businessOpen + '\'' +
            ", businessClose='" + businessClose + '\'' +
            ", type='" + type + '\'' +
            ", title='" + title + '\'' +
            ", latitude='" + latitude + '\'' +
            ", longitude='" + longitude + '\'' +
            ", city='" + city + '\'' +
            ", distance='" + distance + '\'' +
            '}';
}
}
```

Instruction for use this solution:

```
Response response = new Response(jsonObject);
```

Instruction for use it, when you use Retrofit2.
For first we need to create custom factory, create class with name ResponseRetrofitConverter, and this following code :

```
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;

import okhttp3.ResponseBody;
import retrofit2.Converter;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;

public class ResponseRetrofitConverter extends Converter.Factory {

public static ResponseRetrofitConverter create() {
    return new ResponseRetrofitConverter();
}

@Override
public Converter<ResponseBody, ?> responseBodyConverter(Type type, Annotation[] annotations, Retrofit retrofit) {
    return new JsonConverter();
}

private final static class JsonConverter implements Converter<ResponseBody, Response> {

    @Override
    public Response convert(@NonNull ResponseBody responseBody) {
        try {
            return new Response(new JSONObject(responseBody.string()));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
}
```

When Response is your entity,
Add connect with factory to retrofit use following code line :

```
.addConverterFactory(ResponseRetrofitConverter.create())
```

For example my code:

```
Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(link)
            .addConverterFactory(ResponseRetrofitConverter.create())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
```

Comment: toString method I was add only for debug. You can remove it, if you don't need it.

Comment: Thanks Vova Stelmashchuk.. Can you explain how to add this solution for retrofit API call?

Comment: What version of retrofit you use? @UdithaAmarasinghe

Comment: com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0  @VovaStelmashchuk

Comment: I edited my answer, can you check? @UdithaAmarasinghe

Comment: Thank for reply. I added your code, but I got null for response, Please help me @VovaStelmashchuk

Comment: Call me in the viber on telegram +380971493220 @UdithaAmarasinghe

Comment: thank you very much.. appreciate your help and support. @VovaStelmashchuk

Answer (score 0):

You should create a java `List` of objects to represent the data.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to bind a Json that has a number as name, and if you are using jackson as json library, you can declare the variable as follow:

```
@JsonProperty("0")
private CustomObject zero;
@JsonProperty("1")
private CustomObject one;
public CustomObject getZero()
{
    return this.zero;
}
public void setZero(CustomObject zero)
{
    this.zero= zero;
}

public CustomObject getOne()
{
    return this.one;
}
public void setOne(CustomObject one)
{
    this.one= one;
}
```

Comment: I assume he is using GSON cause it goes hand in hand with retrofit.

Comment: Ok, yes, I did not notice that.
My solution is the equivalent for Jackson. But using @SerializedName("0") is the best way for @Uditha Amarasinghe's problem

Answer (score 0):

You can call you class `_0`, `_1`... even it's a little bit strange.

Comment: Why post an answer that's the same as my answer, without adding ANY value to it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Gson then you can use as follows:

```
public class Model{

@SerializedName("0")
private String object;

}
```