# GSON for Web Service

Tags: java, json, web-services, gson

About one hour ago, I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45208322/how-to-create-java-getters-and-setters-when-object-key-is-number) question, I just read and I get the new 'things' called `GSON`. I really new heard that. I search and read about GSON but there is one question in my head which unanswered by Google.

I'm learning about how to build a `Web Service` for Mobile App, just simple `Web Service` like `CRUD` data String, Int, or etc and make an output `JSON`. In my knowledge, there are many way to build it but can I use the `GSON` to do that? Like store and retrieve data to the `SQL` and get the `JSON` output? Any suggestion or answer will help for me. Thanks In Advance

*Edit :
I have read [this](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Finer-Points-with-Objects) , [this](https://blog.ajduke.in/2013/07/28/getting-started-with-google-gson/) and [this wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gson)

Comment: What exactly you want to do with GSON ?

Comment: if can, i want to make a service using GSON in a hosting. I love to know anything about this GSON

Comment: GSON is just library to serialize java object to JSON format nothing else it is not frame work like REST or SOAP that can build Web Service.

Comment: If you wanted to know more about GSON the go to the source code  of Google GSON : https://github.com/google/gson

Comment: So GSON cant do that ya,  well thanks for your suggestion. I will read more about it

Answer (score 2):

GSON mostly use to convert java Object into JSON format.. you can get details of Java Object by parsing... retrieve information

Gson provides four annotations, as documented in the Java Doc. These annotations can be grouped into three categories. Each category is discussed separately.

Gson provides two types of conversion: serialisation (from Java to JSON) and deserialisation (from JSON to Java). Java fields marked transient are excluded from both serialisation and deserialisation. Therefore, sensitive information that should not be serialised can be marked as transient and Gson will not serialised to JSON.

Gson also provides finer serialisation and deserialisation control and filtration. With Gson we can control what is serialised and deserialised independently using only annotations. Alternatively, we can use a custom JsonDeserializer (as described in the article Gson Deserialiser Example) and a custom JsonSerializer (as described in the article Gson Serialiser Example). While these interfaces provide complete control and flexibility, but the annotation approach described in this article is simpler as it does not require additional classes as we will see in the follow example.

with use of gson your line of code in less then other tech--
fast and re-useful in projec..

yes you can bind with database too

for more details i give links click on it..

Comment: http://www.javacreed.com/gson-annotations-example/

Comment: if it is useful for you pls increase my point

Comment: Thanks for explanation, but i knew it before. If i want to develop a Web Service using gson so i just code it and upload in hosting? It just it?

Comment: check this one for gson web service parse json data

Comment: https://kylewbanks.com/blog/Tutorial-Android-Parsing-JSON-with-GSON

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1159537/Simple-JSON-REST-consumption-with-GSON-API

Comment: http://javabeat.net/invoking-restful-web-service-using-api-in-java-net-and-gson/

Comment: http://blog.sodhanalibrary.com/2015/07/java-restful-web-services-using-google.html#.WXCGWnWGObk

Comment: are you build in spring or else?